# Load Modal on page load & redirect after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I got a modal pop up but has no trigger on it. So its not displaying on page which is perfect. But.

How can i display the modal on page load & also force them to redirect to a page.

Comment: Are you using a framework such as bootstrap or foundation etc...? Hard to tell what your modal code looks like with no example code - can you post what you have so far? Help us help you.

Comment: i got bootstrap modal.
`<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>`

Comment: Something like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/about.php" /> `? Because you mentioned on page load, I think you can use meta tag.

Answer (score 3):

Using bootstrap, you open a modal like so:

```
$('#idOfYourModal').modal('show');
```

If you want to redirect after a certain time, then you should look at setTimeout, something like:

```
setTimeout(function{ window.location="your/redirect/url.ext";}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Oening Modal on page load and redirect after five seconds

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Open modal on page load
$("#modal").modal('show');
//redirect after 5seconds
  setInterval(function(){
   window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
   },5000)

})
```

Comment: `setTimout` is needed here, not `setInterval` :)

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use a setTimeout in this instance :)

Comment: in this case you have call redirect , use setTimeout or setInterval both work same.